# Host name and port for Python Websockets on Azure Web Apps

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-web-app-service

Spoiler, I am quite new to this. So my question might be stupid.

Anyways, I am currently using the 'Websockets' API for Python 3.5 in a project that will be hosted on a Azure Web App. When creating the Websocket server using `websockets.serve(WS_HANDLER, HOST, PORT)` I want to specify the host somehow. For envelopment I just set it as localhost with port 8xxx, but I am struggling to know which `HOST` and `PORT` to use in production/deployment. I assume that you can access the `HOST` via som OS variable, but I can't find any information regarding it.
Or is all of this handled by the `web.config` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't that difficult after all.
In order to reach my websocket server from the outside world I did set the `HOST` to `0.0.0.0` and the `PORT` to `os.environ['PORT']`. The `PORT` environmental variable was set in `web.config` as: `<environmentVariable name="PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />` after which I added it to the `httpPlatform` arguments as: `<httpPlatform arguments="main.py --port %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%"> .... </httpPlatform>`.

More information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service