# Websocket falling back to pooling in Azure Web App Python

Tags: azure-web-app-service, flask-socketio

I deployed a Python 3.10 + Flask Websocket on Azure Web App.
During runtime, it falls back to pooling.
In the stream log, there are these events below:

```
 - 2023-07-05T08:31:25.786184617Z     raise RuntimeError('You need to
   use the gevent-websocket server. '
   
   2023-07-05T08:31:25.786188575Z RuntimeError: You need to use the
   gevent-websocket server. See the Deployment section of the
   documentation for more information.
```

How can I fix this? I already have these two in my requirements.txt:

```
gevent==22.10.2
gevent-websocket==0.10.1
```

Is there any special setting I need to set in the Azure Web App ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working steps:

1. Install simple-websocket
2. Update requirements.txt with simple-websocket
3. Add to App Service's Startup Command: gunicorn -w 1 --threads 1000 app:app
4. Redeploy

Answer (score 0):

In the [configuartion](https://gitlab.com/noppo/gevent-websocket), you must first turn ON the WEB [SOCKETS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/) option

From [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-python-vscode?tabs=windows%2Cvs-code-set-indexing-flag&pivots=python-mode-decorators) to install package from required.txt.

- use pip to install the packages you defined `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`,  `pip install flask flask-socketio`
- Create a file `requirements.txt` with the following [content](https://github.com/prashanthmadi/azure-appservice-py-websocket/blob/master/requirements.txt).

```
gevent

gevent-websocket
```

- [websocket python](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo_wsgi)
- [Web app - Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode)

```py
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = true
```

- [Configure of  Linux Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#wsgi-handler)
- [WebSockets on Azure Web Sites](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/)

[image]

- Configure your Python webapp using WSGI on Azure IIS, and you can use the instructional content as a [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#wsgi-handler).
- Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137449/combining-websockets-and-wsgi-in-a-python-app) and [git](https://github.com/duanhongyi/dwebsocket) for more details.

Comment: 0. In the configuration, you must first turn ON the WEB SOCKETS option
-> This option no longer available. Maybe it is enabled by default?

```
1. Installed:
gevent
gevent-websocket

2. Added to requirements.txt:
gevent
gevent-websocket

3. Added .deployment
[config]
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true

4. Redeployed but still in polling mode.
```

This is the sample I tried: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/tree/main/example

Comment: for more details to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50971911/host-name-and-port-for-python-websockets-on-azure-web-apps) and [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438910/python-websocket-support-on-azure-web-appservice).

Comment: Tried the web.config way but also not working. Python on Windows no longer supported. Does web.config still relevant?

Comment: For issue-related WebSocket refer to [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/31771).

Comment: Tried the startup commands such as 'gunicorn -k gevent -w 1 module:app' but throwing error

Comment: The faq link in the link above is going to 404.
And my env is python in linux web app.

Another link [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/faqs-app-service-linux#feedback) doesn't have much info for Python,

Comment: it loads well while clicking on [it](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/31771). Using the WebSocket server is required, according to the error message you are currently seeing. In your requirements.txt file, you've already installed it however, you might still need to make some adjustments in the Azure Web App. To install a package from requirements.txt.

Comment: I meant the link Content Source: articles/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-faq.md in the article

Comment: any way,


    I installed simple-websocket,  

    My requirement txt: https://gist.github.com/huislaw/fe13eaeb41c7b656e56112a0e48bb174,   

    Deployed to: https://testhssocketio.azurewebsites.net/ ,   

    It shows connected, but Current transport is: polling,   

    Deployment log: https://gist.github.com/huislaw/46943d3591157a72275cf8dc997eb86b

    (Doesn't seems to have error)
,
    After enabling log for app service I get this error:
    https://gist.github.com/huislaw/c7bc0e3d14c185fc6001ffa86c4685e8
,  I'm not sure what is this error about. Do you have any idea?

Comment: it is solved by adding to App Service's Startup Command: gunicorn -w 1 --threads 1000 app:app

Comment: Good that issue resolved  with           ```gunicorn -w 1 --threads 1000 app:app```